# Python re.findall() with pattern .* returns empty string along the matching pattern

Tags: python, regex-greedy

I did browse many docs and videos before posting this question here. I didn't find the exact **reason** for this.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r'.*', 'sample text').group()
'sample text'
>>> re.findall(r'.*', 'sample text')
['sample text', '']
>>>
```

### **Unclear part:**

In the output `['sample text', '']`

1. Why is empty-string('') returned after matched string?

I am aware of this behaviour but couldn't find the **reasons for this behaviour**.

2. How do I get rid of this?

Could someone please help me understand this.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's coming up with two matches, but you could prevent it by specifying the begin/end of string in your regex: `re.findall(r'^.*$', 'sample text')`

Comment: Well the empty string does match at the end.

Comment: how about this `re.findall(r'.+', 'sample text')`